# I'm getting this "Maximum update depth exceeded." while trying to handle firebase authentication error with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm using react firebase hooks library for firebase authentication. I'm trying to handle signInWithEmailAndPassword error using useEffect but getting this infinite error. "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render."

````
const [signInWithEmailAndPassword, user, loading, error] =
    useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [errors, setError] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(info.email, info.password);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      switch (error?.code) {
        case "auth/user-not-found":
          setError({
            ...errors,
            email: "No user found using that email",
          });
          setInfo({ ...info, email: "" });
          break;
        case "auth/wrong-password":
          setError({ ...errors, password: "Wrong password" });
          setInfo({ ...info, email: "" });
          break;
        default:
          toast.error("Something went wrong");
          break;
      }
    }
  }, [error, errors, info]);```
````

Comment: Because your useEffect depends on things that you're setting in there, each time they change it gets called again. Create different state for the error you set in there rather than writing over the one you're depending on.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit. Should I create another state for handling the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `useEffect` will re-run whenever `errors` or `info` changes due to it depending on it: `[error, errors, info]`. So you will run into an infinite loop when you set `setErrors` or `setInfo` in there.

In this case the fix is quite simple - if you use the function callback version of `setErrors`/`setInfo` it will pass you `errors`/`info` without needing to pull it in as a dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (error) {
    switch (error?.code) {
      case "auth/user-not-found":
        setErrors(errors => ({
          ...errors,
          email: "No user found using that email",
        }));
        setInfo(info => ({ ...info, email: "" }));
        break;
      case "auth/wrong-password":
        setErrors(errors => ({ ...errors, password: "Wrong password" }));
        setInfo(info => ({ ...info, email: "" }));
        break;
      default:
        toast.error("Something went wrong");
        break;
    }
  }
}, [error]);
```

(Note I renamed from `setError` to `setErrors` as I found it confusing since the variable is called `errors` (plural))

Comment: VS code is also asking for "info" dependency don't know why. But it's working without that. Thanks.

Comment: @TahjibAlSakin I missed one above: `setInfo(info => ({ ...info, email: "" }));`, edited